# Passing columns to kableExtra arguments within dplyr

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

I'm trying to use kable and kableExtra to format tables created using pipes, and I can't get the conditional formatting arguments (`row_spec`, `column_spec`) to accept variables piped from the generated code.

In the toy example below I create a variable called `bg` within the dataframe that I want to use to create bands of background colour, but `row_spec` and `column_spec` don't seem to recognize that as a variable. Note that *creating the variable outside of the pipes isn't an option* - the actual use case is much more complicated than that, and the variables used in the process don't exist before that.

```
library(kableExtra)
set.seed(111)

df = data.frame(var1 = sort(sample(LETTERS[1:3],10,TRUE)),
                var2 = sample(1:4,10,TRUE),
                var3 = runif(10,0,1))
df %>%
  mutate(bg = cumsum(!duplicated(var1))%%2)%>%
  kable() %>%kable_styling()%>%
  column_spec(1,color=bg)

Error in ensure_len_html(color, nrows, "color") : object 'bg' not found
```

**EDIT**: You can do it in two steps easily enough, so I'll include that here, as well as the resulting table that I'm looking for

```
d = df %>%
  mutate(bg = cumsum(!duplicated(var1))%%2)
kable(d) %>% kable_styling(full_width=FALSE) %>% 
  row_spec(which(d$bg==1),background=grey(0.75))
```

[image]

Comment: What about ```color=spec_color(df$bg)```?

Comment: @bttomio yeah I thought of that, but `bg` isn't a component of `df`, it's created within the command.  I thought that `.[['bg']]` would work, but no dice.

Comment: What are you knitting to? PDF, Word, HTML?

Comment: @LMc HTML most of the time - sometimes to PDF but I think we'll focus on getting HTML working first

Answer (score 2):

This might work:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

set.seed(111)
df = data.frame(var1 = sort(sample(LETTERS[1:3],10,TRUE)),
                var2 = sample(1:4,10,TRUE),
                var3 = runif(10,0,1))

df %>%
  mutate(bg = cumsum(!duplicated(var1))%%2) %>%
  mutate(bg = cell_spec(bg, color = spec_color(bg))) %>%
  kable(escape = F) %>% kable_styling()
```

Output:

[image]

You may find more information here (page 16): https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf

Version with background color:

```
df %>%
  mutate(bg = cumsum(!duplicated(var1))%%2) %>%
  mutate(bg = cell_spec(bg, color = "white", bold = T,
                        background = spec_color(bg))) %>%
  kable(escape = F) %>% kable_styling()
```

Output with background color:

[image]

Comment: Yeah that's not a terrible solution, but background coloring doesn't work well with `cell_spec`, and I'd have to do each column individually, which seems like more work than just doing the kable separately.

Comment: You don't have to do each column individually, you can do `mutate(across(everything(), ~ cell_spec(., spec_color(bg))))`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just added a version with background color. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: It's better, but I want row-shading, not cell shading - I'll add the 2-step solution to my example, that's probably the best solution for now.